# R Shiny photos not rendering upon deployment

Tags: r, shiny

I have written a dashboard code that works in my console viewer but is failing upon deployment...
There are three tabs on the website, two with plot that generate within the code and another that displays all images with the filename pattern "_balance.jpg". Here is a snipped of my server code:

```
# Reactive expression to get the list of files ending with "_balance.jpg"
  output$image_list <- renderUI({
    folder_path <- "C:/Users/hmdavid/Box/HMDavid@mednet.ucla.edu/Cheng/Financials/Cheng_Finance"  # Update this line
   addResourcePath(prefix = 'pics', directoryPath = folder_path)
   # filenames <- list.files(path = "pics", pattern = "_balance.jpg", full.names = TRUE)
    # Update this line
   filenames <- list.files(path = folder_path, pattern = "_balance.jpg", full.names = TRUE)
    print(filenames)
    if (length(filenames) > 0) {
      # Render images
      tagList(
        h3("Rendered images:"),
        tags$div(
          lapply(filenames, function(filename) {
            img(src = paste0("pics/", basename(filename)), width = 400, height = 300, alt = basename(filename))
          })
        )
      )
    } else {
      # Placeholder message if no files are found
      tagList(
        h3("No images found in the working directory.")
      )
    }
```

The error in my Shiny log is

```
Couldn't normalize path in `addResourcePath`, with arguments: `prefix` = 'pics';
   `directoryPath` = 'C:/Users/XXXX/Box/XXXX.edu/Cheng/Financials/Cheng_Finance'
```

adding in the line with addResourcepath() is the only thing that has gotten the images to generate in my console.

The path within the shiny deployment where the images are stored is different than the path of the files in my computer but I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: Are you expecting that a remote server (perhaps shinyapps.io or an instance of Posit Connect) is going to have absolute access to your entire local `C:/` drive? (Hint: that's an incredibly bad idea for many reasons.) You'll need to copy the file you need into a subdirectory of your `app.R` (or `ui.R` and `server.R`) file, typically within a `www/` subdir.

Comment: And just to add - those files need to be bundled with the app files when you deploy them - the server will never have access to your drives.

Comment: I know that the local directory won't work but am unsure of exactly how to change my path for these images to get them to render in the website. All of the files are uploaded to the remote server when i deploy the script for publish.